# Combining observations based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, diff

Currently I am writing my master's thesis, however, I have some issues with combining rows on multiple conditions. I have illustrated my problem and desired outcome below. I hope you can help me :).

This is an example of how my dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  userID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  sessionID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  date = as.Date(c("2019-03-15", "2019-03-18", "2019-03-19", "2019-03-21","2019-03-30", "2019-04-05", 
                   "2019-06-06", "2019-11-22", "2019-12-22", "2019-12-24", "2020-01-15"), 
                 format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
  purchase=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))
```

Now, I have calculated the difference via diff via dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(userID) %>%
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date))
```

However, I want to combine the rows if there is < 10 days of difference between them. I would like that the 10 days window resets every time there is an activity (a new sessionID). Furthermore, when purchase is 1 then it stops, and the 10 day window will start again when there is a new sessionID.

I have tried many things with the functions filter and summarise in dplyr, but it gives not the desired result. Besides, I do not really know how to include the purchase condition.

My desired outcome would look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  userID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  sessionID = c("1 + 2", "3 + 4 + 5", "1", "2", "1", "2 + 3", "4"),
  date.start = as.Date(c("2019-03-15","2019-03-19", "2019-04-05", 
                   "2019-06-06", "2019-11-22", "2019-12-22", "2020-01-15"), 
                 format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
  date.end = as.Date(c("2019-03-18", "2019-03-30", "2019-04-05", "2019-06-06", 
                     "2019-11-22", "2019-12-24", "2020-01-15"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),  
  purchase=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0))
```

I hope you can help me :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouped by 'userID', create a new group based on the occurrence of 1 in 'purchase' by doing the cumulative sum on the `lag` of 'purchase', then create another grouping based on the `diff`erence in adjacent 'date' values i.e. checking if the difference is greater than or equal to 10 days, do a cumulative sum, and `summarise` the 'sessionID' by pasting ([`str_c`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_c)), get the `first` element of 'date' and `last` of 'date' and `any` value of 1 in 'purchase' as summary columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(userID) %>%
    group_by( grp = cumsum(lag(purchase, 
        default = first(purchase))), .add = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(cat = cumsum(difftime(date, 
      lag(date, default = first(date)), units = 'day') >= 10), .add = TRUE ) %>%
    summarise(sessionID = str_c(sessionID, collapse= ' + '), 
              date.start = first(date), date.end = last(date), 
               purchase = +(any(purchase == 1)), .groups = 'drop' ) %>%
    select(-grp, -cat)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  userID sessionID date.start date.end   purchase
   <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>        <int>
1      1 1 + 2     2019-03-15 2019-03-18        1
2      1 3 + 4 + 5 2019-03-19 2019-03-30        0
3      2 1         2019-04-05 2019-04-05        0
4      2 2         2019-06-06 2019-06-06        0
5      3 1         2019-11-22 2019-11-22        0
6      3 2 + 3     2019-12-22 2019-12-24        1
7      3 4         2020-01-15 2020-01-15        0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works very nice with the example, however, I cannot reproduce it with my original dataset. Does it matter if userID and sessionId are defined as characters?

Comment: @Andre it shouldn't matter because I am only `paste`ing the sessionID

Comment: @Andre it is possible that you may have NAs in your original data which creates some issue in `cumsum`

Comment: The problem with reproducing the example lies in the last four lines of the example (so, userID 3). In the example it works. For my original dataset I get back the following: userid: 3; sessionid: 4 + 3; start.date: 2020-01-15; end.date: 2019-12-14; purchase: 1. & the other row is userid: 3; sessionid: 2 + 1; start.date: 2019-12-22; end.date 2019-11-22, purchase: 0.

Comment: CAn you check what is different in that data compared to this example.  Are the columns `date` class

Comment: @Andre you are using `strptime` which is POSIXlt class instead of `POSIXct` and here in the example we used `Date` class

Comment: These are the lines is used: Sample1$newdate <- strptime(as.character(Sample1$date), "%Y%m%d") AND
Sample1$newdate <- as.Date(Sample1$newdate , format = "%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: I used strptime to turn the old date ("%Y%m%d") into a new date variable, which is done with as.Date in format of "%Y-%m-%d". I thought that this would do it.

Comment: @Andre `strptime` returns a different structure i.e. `list` compared to `as.POSIXct` or `as.Date`

Comment: How can I fix it? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of a small example so that I can test it

Comment: Sample_structure <-
  structure(list(
    userID = c(
      "1807706496.1575927561",
      "629852243.1548697289",
      "654039718.1575027975"
    ),
    sessionID = c(
      "1575929935176.xh9r5avk",
      "1557698044554.44szfncf",
      "1575028026142.kund6oa9"
    ),
    date = c(20191209L,
             20190512L, 20191129L),
    purchase = c(0, 0, 0)
  ),
  row.names = c(2693899L,
                604512L, 2539259L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @Andre have you tried `Sample_structure %>% mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% group_by(userID) %>%
    group_by( grp = cumsum(lag(purchase, 
        default = first(purchase))), .add = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(cat = cumsum(difftime(date, 
      lag(date, default = first(date)), units = 'day') >= 10), .add = TRUE ) %>%  summarise(sessionID = str_c(sessionID, collapse= ' + '), 
              date.start = first(date), date.end = last(date), 
               purchase = +(any(purchase == 1)), .groups = 'drop' ) %>%
    select(-grp, -cat)`

Comment: Yes, I have just tried it, but I get the same output as mentioned previously

Comment: What is your expected output for that

Comment: In the example you showed, there are only 3 rows and each userID is different

Comment: The_Example <- 
structure(
  list(
    userID = c(
      "2036713846.1563089854",
      "2036713846.1563089854",
      "2036713846.1563089854",
      "2036713846.1563089854"
    ),
    sessionID = c(
      "1579122007882.xaneaymm",
      "1577214285712.imtgu7jh",
      "1577031528866.31bhe0ws",
      "1574432043802.bae9kc5"
    ),
    date = c(20200115L, 20191224L, 20191222L, 20191122L),
    purchase = c(0,
                 1, 0, 0)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-4L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

Comment: @Andre Now, the summary output returns 2 rows

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried to explain in the fourth  comment

Comment: @Andre what is the issue in that 2 rows.

Comment: @Andre Or can you update your post with your expected and the input you shared so that it is easy to understand. thanks

Comment: I have fixed it by adding the arrange(date) function. Thank you for the help and quick responses! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Another tidyverse strategy using `accumulate2`

```r
df <- data.frame(
  userID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  sessionID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  date = as.Date(c("2019-03-15", "2019-03-18", "2019-03-19", "2019-03-21","2019-03-30", "2019-04-05", 
                   "2019-06-06", "2019-11-22", "2019-12-22", "2019-12-24", "2020-01-15"), 
                 format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
  purchase=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(userID, grp = cumsum(sessionID == 1) ) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(date - lag(date, default = first(date)))) %>%
  group_by(grp2 = accumulate2(diff, purchase[-n()], ~if(..2 > 10 | ..3 == 1) ..1 + 1 else ..1), .add = T) %>%
  summarise(sessionID = paste(sessionID, collapse = ' + '),
            start_date = first(date),
            end_date = last(date), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  select(!starts_with('grp'))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   userID sessionID start_date end_date  
#>    <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>    
#> 1      1 1 + 2     2019-03-15 2019-03-18
#> 2      1 3 + 4 + 5 2019-03-19 2019-03-30
#> 3      2 1         2019-04-05 2019-04-05
#> 4      2 2         2019-06-06 2019-06-06
#> 5      3 1         2019-11-22 2019-11-22
#> 6      3 2 + 3     2019-12-22 2019-12-24
#> 7      3 4         2020-01-15 2020-01-15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Dedicated to my dear friend @akrun**
Here is just another way of achieving the final output, It is not as elegant and as concise as the one dear @akrun proposed. In fact I spent a couple hours on this and It was very important to me to see the end of it. However I was greatly inspired by dear @Akrun as always. I hope it works for you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(cum = cumsum(purchase == 1),
         cum = ifelse(cum - lag(cum, default = 0) == 1, lag(cum), cum), 
         Days = as.numeric(date - lag(date, default = first(date)))) %>%
  group_by(cum) %>%
  mutate(diff = ifelse(Days < 10, 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(diff = cumsum(diff), 
         start = date, 
         end = date) %>%
  mutate(across(sessionID, as.character)) %>%
  group_split(userID, cum, diff) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, userID = .x$userID[1], 
                    sessionID = paste(.x$sessionID, collapse = "+"), 
                    start = .x$date[1], end = .x$date[length(.x$date)])) %>%
  filter(if_any(date:diff, ~ is.na(.x))) %>%
  select(!date:diff)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
  userID sessionID start      end       
   <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>    
1      1 1+2       2019-03-15 2019-03-18
2      1 3+4+5     2019-03-19 2019-03-30
3      2 1         2019-04-05 2019-04-05
4      2 2         2019-06-06 2019-06-06
5      3 1         2019-11-22 2019-11-22
6      3 2+3       2019-12-22 2019-12-24
7      3 4         2020-01-15 2020-01-15
```